# is there a way to test methods of these kind using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

since this method is executed at runtime is there need to test it

```
public void addListener(RepeatRejectAnalysis_Listener rralistener)
{
    Save_Button.addActionListener(rralistener);
    Cancel_Button.addActionListener(rralistener);
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the other question: your naming patterns are **not** standard java; you should do some learning there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it doesn't feel that there is a need to test this type of methods because there is no business logic.

However, if you are eager to do it, you could check that `addActionListener` method is called for two different objects with the same input parameter. Similar like this:

```
// SETUP SUT
RepeatRejectAnalysis_Listener yourRraListener = new RepeatRejectAnalysis_Listener(); 

// EXERCISE
yourClass.addListener(yourRraListener);

// VERIFY
Mockito.verify(Save_Button, Mockito.times(1)).addActionListener(yourRraListener);
Mockito.verify(Cancel_Button, Mockito.times(1)).addActionListener(yourRraListener);
```

In this case you need to mock your `Save_Button` and `Cancel_Button` in your test.

Answer (score 2):

You might not even need a Mocking framework here.

If you have access to your buttons; you can simply invoke that method; and afterwards **assert** that each button has that new listener within its list of ActionListeners.

In other words: you **only** mock things when that object is **hard** to create in your unit test environment. For example: some client that wants to talk to a database probably needs mocking; but a simple JButton ... probably not.

Please understand: mocking frameworks are always the **second** choice. If possible, you want to assert/verify directly on your production code elements. So instead of mocking buttons, focus on being able to run your tests with **real** buttons and use the interfaces that those provide in order to verify the expected behavior.